# Convert Nepali date to english date using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I have Nepali date in employment table of kep database  and i want to convert this date in to English date using postgresql.Guide me please.
Here is my table

```
id   date
1    2071/1/4
2    2071/1/29
3    2069/4/24
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ff85f/1)</kbd>

1) Import list of nepali years and length of each month (I copied data from [here](http://shrestha-manoj.blogspot.cz/2012/06/convert-english-date-to-nepali-date-in.html)). In first column there is nepali year and in other columns there is length of each month in days (second column in table is length of first month in every year).

```
-- drop table if exists tmpcal;

create table tmpcal (nyear int, a int, b int, c int, d int, e int, f int, g int, h int, i int, j int, k int, l int);

insert into tmpcal values
(2000 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2001 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2002 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2003 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2004 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2005 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2006 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2007 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2008 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31),
(2009 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2010 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2011 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2012 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2013 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2014 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2015 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2016 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2017 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2018 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2019 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2020 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2021 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2022 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
(2023 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2024 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2025 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2026 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2027 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2028 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2029 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2030 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2031 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2032 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2033 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2034 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2035 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31),
(2036 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2037 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2038 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2039 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2040 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2041 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2042 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2043 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2044 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2045 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2046 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2047 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2048 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2049 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
(2050 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2051 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2052 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2053 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
(2054 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2055 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2056 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2057 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2058 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2059 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2060 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2061 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2062 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2063 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2064 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2065 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2066 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31),
(2067 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2068 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2069 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2070 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2071 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2072 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2073 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
(2074 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2075 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2076 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
(2077 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
(2078 , 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2079 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
(2080 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
(2081 , 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2082 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2083 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2084 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2085 , 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2086 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2087 , 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2088 , 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2089 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
(2090 , 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30);
```

2) Assign date to every nepali date:

- first convert columns into rows (using `union all`)
- then we generate nepali days (using `generate_series()`)
- at the end we number rows (using `row_number()`) and add this number to 1943-04-14 date and substract 1 (used [this](http://www.rajan.com/calendar/convertn.asp) converter to match nepali date 2000/01/01 to common date).

.

```
-- drop table if exists cal_conversion;

create table cal_conversion as (

with tmp as (

  select nyear, 1::int as nmonth, a as nday from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 2, b from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 3, c from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 4, d from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 5, e from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 6, f from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 7, g from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 8, h from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 9, i from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 10, j from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 11, k from tmpcal union all
  select nyear, 12, l from tmpcal

)

select
  *,
  nyear || '/' || nmonth || '/' || nday as ndate,
  '1943-04-14'::date + row_number() over(order by nyear, nmonth, nday)::int - 1 as edate
from (
select 
  nyear,
  nmonth,
  generate_series(1, nday) as nday
   from tmp) x

 );
```

3) Finally, use our conversion table:

Sample data:

```
-- drop table if exists test_data;

create table test_data (
  id int,
  ndate varchar);

insert into test_data values
  (1,'2071/1/4'),
  (2,'2071/1/29'),
  (3,'2069/4/24');
```

Usage (simple join):

```
select
  ndate,
  id,
  edate
from 
  test_data
  join cal_conversion using (ndate);
```

Result:

```
2069/4/24;3;2012-08-08
2071/1/29;2;2014-05-12
2071/1/4;1;2014-04-17
```